# Azure changing hardware

Tags: azure

I have a product which uses CPU ID, network MAC, and disk volume serial numbers for validation.  Basically when my product is first installed these values are recorded and then when the app is loaded up, these current values are compared against the old ones.

Something very mysterious happened recently.  Inside of an Azure VM that had not been restarted in weeks, my app failed to load because some of these values were different.  Unfortunately the person who caught the error deleted the VM before it was brought to my attention.

My question is, when an Azure VM is running, what hardware resources may change?  Is that even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Was it a full VM or just a service role?

Answer (score 5):

Answering this requires a short rundown of how Azure works.

In each data centres there are thousands of individual machines. Each machine runs a hypervisor which allows a number of operating systems to share the same underlying hardware.

When you start a role, Azure looks for available resources - disk space CPU RAM etc and boots up a copy of the appropriate OS VM in thoe avaliable resources. I understand from your question that this is a VM role - so this VM is the one you uploaded or created.

As long as your VM is running, the underlying virtual resources provided by the hypervisor are not likely to change. (the caveat to this is that windows server 2012's hyper visor can move virtual machines around over the network even while they are running. Whether azure takes advantage of this, I don't know)

Now, Azure keeps charging you for even when your role has stopped because it considers your role "deployed". So in theory, those underlying resources  still "belong" to your role.

This is not guaranteed. Azure could decided to boot up your VM on a different set of virtualized hardware for any number of reasons - hardware failure being at the top of the list, with insufficient capacity being second.

It is even possible (tho unlikely) for your resources to be provided by different hardware nodes.

An additional point of consideration is that it is Azure policy that disaster recovery (or other major event) may include transferring your roles to run in a separate data centre entirely.

My point is that the underlying hardware is virtual and treating it otherwise is most unwise. Roles are at the mercy of the Azure Management Routines, and we can't predict in advance what decisions they may make.

So the answer to your question is that ALL of the underlying resources may change. And it is very, very possible.

Comment: Thanks for this fantastic bit of information, Roberto.  Knowing the details that you do, would you have any suggestions on Azure VM "constants" that I may use in place of the hardware constants (which are obviously not constant in Azure).

Comment: The overall sentiment of this answer is correct (the hardware may change at any time), but there are a few things to clear up:
* Azure today does not do live migration of VMs
* Insufficient capacity will not cause a movement of your VM. Only hardware failures will cause this.
* One VM runs on one physical node.  There is no concept of different hardware nodes providing resources for one VM.
* Azure will never move your VM to a different data center.

Comment: Thanks kwill.  I haven't been able to find much information on this topic; could you share some of your sources?

Comment: The Instance Id is one such property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleinstance_properties.aspx. And the role name is another - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.role_properties.aspx

Comment: Kwill - All of those things are unlikely - but technically possible in future. And Azure's SLA agreement specifically includes a clause that covers moving your Roles and data to a different data centre when needed for data recovery.